# Vector elements are not swapped in partition algorithm.

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Problem is from the Elements of Programming Interviews Book (2012). 
Problem 6.1 pg 53: "Write a functions that take an array A (I used vector) and an index i into A, and rearranges the elements such that all elements less than A[i] appear first, followed by elements equal to A[i], followed by elements greater than A[i]. Your algorithm should have O(1) space complexity and O(|A|) time complexity.

My code doesn't do anything to the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


template <typename T>

void swapit(vector<T> v, int i, int j)
{
    T temp;
    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}

template <typename T>

void dutch_flag_partition(vector<T> &v, int pivotindex)
{
    T pivot = v[pivotindex];
    int lower = 0;
    int equals = 0;
    int larger = v.size() - 1;
    while(equals <= larger)
    {
        cout << equals << " " << larger<< endl;
        if(v[equals] < pivot)
        {
            swapit(v, lower++, equals++);
        }
        else if(v[equals] == pivot)
        {
            ++equals;
        }
        else
        {
            swapit(v, equals, larger--);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,11,3,5,3,10,0,22,50,33,4,22,23,100,9};
    vector<int> v (arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    dutch_flag_partition(v, 5);

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to pass the vector by reference in your swapit function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void swapit(vector<T> v, int i, int j) { ... }
```

This does not modify the vector you passed in. Instead, it creates a copy for this function. You probably want to use a reference:

```
void swapit(vector<T> & v, int i, int j) { ... }
```